# How to adjust timeout for python app served with waitress

Tags: python, flask, timeout, gateway, waitress

I am running a flask application which has an option in the UI where the user can click a button and it calls an endpoint to perform some analysis.

The application is served as follows:

```
from waitress import serve
serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

After around ~1 minute, I am receiving a gateway timeout in the UI:
[504 Gatway Time-out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7PB6.png)

However, the flask application keeps doing the work behind and after 2 minutes it completes the processing and I can see that it submits the data on the db side. So the process is not timing out itself.

I tried already passing channel_timeout argument to a much higher value [(default seems 120 seconds)](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/arguments.html) but with no luck. I know that this makes sense to implement in a different way where the user doesn't have to wait for these two minutes, but I am looking if there is such a timeout set by default and whether it can be increased.

The application is deployed in K8s and the UI is exposed via ingress. Could the timeout come from ingress instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the [ingress controller default timeout](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#proxy-connect-timeout).

I managed to get around this issue by changing the implementation and having this job run as background task instead.

Comment: were u able to configure channel_timeout? When I tried to change channel timeout it's not working as expected

Comment: I tried adding `cleanup_interval=90` (default is 30) and solved the timeouts.